# How to change the fontSize of a SliverAppBar.large's title and how to set background image?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and was trying to achieve the iOS appbar's behavior in Contacts app in an iPhone. I got close using the SliverAppBar.large but when the content is being scrolled and the title appears in the center of the appbar, the title's fontSize remains the same as to when the app bar was fully expanded. Here's a link to the flutter page to explain the behavior I'm talking about:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar/SliverAppBar.large.html#material.SliverAppBar.large.1

Another question is that how do I set a background image behind the title? I tried setting it by using the flexibleSpace parameter as shown below, but that hides the title. Even though I tried the same approach with a sliverAppBar where it worked perfectly.

```
flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
  background: Opacity(
    opacity: 0.8,
    child: Image.network(
      kImgLink,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
),
```

So 2 questions:

1. How to reduce the font size of the title when SliverAppBar.large is collapsed and
2. How to set background image?

Comment: I found out that I can achieve the title behavior using CupertinoSliverAppBar but that won't let me have an image as the background.